# Xamarin график с AChartEngine

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, диаграммы, график

Хочу нарисовать график, нашел бесплатную библиотеку [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/). Однако [демо](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine) который там имеется реализован на java. Пытался импортировать этот проект в *Android Studio*, но ругается на отсутствие gradle в проекте.

В примере встречается создание объектов интерфейса(что нельзя сделать в c#) и не получается разобраться как происходит отрисовка самого графика. Понимаю, что рисуется это в `LinearLayout`, но как это делается...

Написал Main.axml по этому примеру

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add_values"
        android:id="@+id/topText" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="71.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/xValue"
            android:layout_marginRight="35.5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="y"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="83.0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/yValue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="51.5dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_series"
            android:text="new_series"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вроде создал объект класса необходимого мне графика и добавил туда серию с точками, но как это нарисовать?

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using AChartEngine.Charts;
using AChartEngine.Models;
using AChartEngine.Renderers;
using AChartEngine;

namespace ChartsAChartEngine
{
    [Activity(Label = "ChartsAChartEngine", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            TextView topText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.topText);
            EditText editTextX = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.xValue);
            EditText editTextY = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.yValue);
            Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.add);
            LinearLayout linearLayoutChart = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.chart);

            var dataSetXY = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            var series = new XYSeries("test");
            series.Add(1, 1); // если в серии есть точки, то падает
            dataSetXY.AddSeries(series);
            var renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            var lineChart = new LineChart(dataSetXY,renderer);
            var view = new GraphicalView(this,lineChart);
            view.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            linearLayoutChart.AddView(view); 

            translateButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                topText.Text = "Ha-ha";
            };
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Давно пользовался этой библиотекой, насколько помню, следующий шаг должен быть:

```
var view = new GraphicalView(context, lineChart)
```

Т.е. создать view на базе графика и как обычно вставить его в разметку.

**Добавлено**
А это не этот же компонент, уже адаптированный под Xamarin?
https://components.xamarin.com/view/achartengine

Comment: Подскажите, а как "вставлять" его в разметку? Попытался сделать так: `linearLayoutChart.AddView(view);` но падает

Comment: Вставлять как обычно, как любой view. А чего падает? Добавьте лог в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Если быть точнее, падает не на этой строке, а с этой строкой

Comment: Скриншот несёт 0 информации, там есть Copy Details в окне Unhandled Exception, может хоть что-то оттуда вытяните?

Comment: " An unhandled exception occured. occurred " это всё что есть из Copy Details

Comment: Экспериментальным путем выяснил что проблема в отображении серии. Если серия пустая, то в LinearLayout присутствует "тёмный прямоугольник"(задний фон) от графика